# How different are arrays from Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I can create 2-d arrays in Perl. How different is 2d arrays from Hash? Why is hash a primitive data structure in perl, when we can simulate the hash features using arrays?

Comment: There are no 2d arrays, there are array of arrays

Comment: There are 2D arrays in PDL, but I know that isn't what the OP meant. (Also they are for numbers only)

Comment: You can also simulate an array with a hash, but it wouldn't make anyone better off if the array wasn't a primitive data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In construction of many types of objects, the `new` method can be passed a list of arguments that may appear as a hash, but it really is just an array, where every even number is a key, and every odd number is a value.

```
my $obj = Some::New::Class->new(
  name => 'Sam',
  age  => 0,
  email => 'sam@localhost'
);
```

This is the equivalent to:

```
my $obj = Some::New::Class->new(
  'name', 'Sam',
  'age', 0,
  'email', 'sam@localhost'
);
```

You can, however, instruct new() to look for a hash, which would appear more like:

```
my $obj = Some::New::Class->new({
  name => 'Sam',
  age  => 0,
  email => 'sam@localhost'
});
```

If this doesn't answer your question, I hope I at least provided some insight.

Comment: you're passing a *reference* to a hash in your last example there, not a hash: so the code to dereference it will be different in the implementation of new(). (You probably knew that, but just to clarify.)

Answer (score 6):

Probably you mean you can have a data structure like this:

```
my $array_hash = [
  [ "key1", "value1" ],
  [ "key2", "value2" ],
];
```

For small data this works well, but consider the case that such an array has about 1000 entries. Then, to find a specific entry by its key, you have to search through the whole array, which is slow.

The primitive hash type allows for quick lookups, and this is exactly what it is used for.

Another reason that hash tables are built into Perl is that they are useful data structures, so not every programmer should need to implement his own.